# Lexing Lisp in Python

Tags: python, lisp

I have been interested by the Lisp language, and I decided to create my own dialect. This is going to be the most simple one to ever exist.

As you know, everything in Lisp is a list (or at least this dialect). A list consists of a command that comes at the start of it, and maybe arguments which are lists themselves. Using this information, I created the following.

```py
class KList:
    def __init__(self, command, args=None):
        self.command = command
        self.args = args
```

So using this structure, `(+ 1 2)` should turn to `KList('+', [KList('1'), KList('2')])` and welp to convert it. I need a lexer and my problem is that. How can I convert it? There are two things that are important to me.

1. I just kind of hate downloading a quadrillion packages for a simple project. So a solution without a lexing library.
2. Lisp is a functional language, and it might seem weird, but I use Python for functional programming, so please avoid statements and mutating variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Lisp parser can be easy to implement, you can basically write a recursive descent top-down parser.
You have individual readers, like readers for integers, strings, symbols, whatever you want:

```
class Reader:

    def read_integer(self, stream):
        pass

    def read_string(self, stream):
        pass

    def read_symbol(self, stream):
        pass

    def read_whitespace(self, stream):
        pass
```

In particular, a reader for compound forms:

```
    def read_open_parenthesis(self, stream):
        # read as many forms as possible until
        # you reach ")"
        pass
```

And you add a main reader that peeks at the stream, check which characters is being read, and calls whatever function it needs:

```py
    def read_form(self, in):
        byte = stream.peek()
        if byte.isdigit():
            return self.read_integer(in)
        if byte == '(':
            _ = in.read_char() # read paren
            return self.read_open_parenthesis(in)
        # etc.
```

In fact, the Common Lisp reader does this, but in a programmable way. There is a *readtable* that associates characters to reader functions, and you can change this *readtable* at runtime. For example all digits in this table are mapped to some `read-integer` function, but you could hack that to have a different reader.

Note also that you are expected to *intern* symbols in Lisp, meaning that you create a symbol the first time you parse it, then use the same symbol object the next time you parse the same symbol, so that symbols are identical.

```
(eq 'a 'a)
=> T
```

Which is not necessarily the case for strings:

```
(eq "a" "a")
=> NIL
```

(it could be T for compiler that optimize away duplicate strings)

From a certain point of view this is a very simple approach, but of course the Common Lisp approach is a little more complex than that, there are a lot of subtelties that you can ignore at first. For a more complete explanation see [2.2 Reader Algorithm](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_b.htm)
.

Comment: that's cool, but I actually include numbers & strings as commands, themselves. I don't know if I'm wrong here, but I wanna go threw a lex -> parse phase. Can you maybe explain the algorithm your-self, since I'm not good at reading documents

Comment: how do you include numbers and strings as commands?!

Comment: In-case a command starts with" & ends with it. It will be a string. Just like that with numbers. In-case it starts with 0-9 or . & ends with them.

Comment: so, you are doing what I am explaining, you are parsing different kind of types based on the first character you see in the source file. That's the idea behind top-down parsing, I'll try to explain better later